# Group Similar elements in PPS Graphs using MDX query - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mdx, performancepoint

Hi All,
I am trying to generate a report using PPS in SharePoint 2010. We have **sem** at the bottom axis.
SQL table is like this.

```
m1 m2 sem year
43 40 A   F 
70 99 A   R 
79 70 A   F 
13 22 A   R 
35 30 C   N 
21 19 I   F 
56 29 I   R
```

Now as table given contains dublicate entries in column **sem**; so it's showing mutiple entries in graph too. Requirement is that at the end it should sum up all dublicate entries in one like **GROUP BY** in Sql. Please guide.

I found one link 
[Grouping MDX query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107529/grouping-mdx-query-results)
But I am not able to understand the answers.

Regards, Vikrant Raj Behal

Comment: Is your data in a Multi-dimensional cube or in a sql table?